# Firefox, and Camino localStorage/Databases

Tags: objective-c, macos, sqlite, html, local-storage

Iv'e searched online, but can't find a definitive answer anywhere. Where exactly do Firefox, and Camino save there localStorage/Databases to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox stores all [web storage data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage#Web_Storage_Management) in a SQLite database named `webappsstore.sqlite` located in your profile directory.

Answer (score 0):

Found sqlite file at
    /Users/[user_name]/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/[profile_name]/webappsstore.sqlite

You can use [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to explore the database.